# Object.keys not printing properly

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to get only keys from the object, but I am getting 0 1 2 3 as output.

Below is my code

```js
data = {"property" : "{\"animalID\": \"12345\", \"animalNumber\" : \"789\", \"type\" : \"mamal\"}"}

onCLick() {
  const dataOne = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data)));
  console.log("data", Object.keys(dataOne.property));
}
```

Below is the current output, which is wrong.

> data (61) ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60']

Trying to achieve something like this

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: You data is not in correct format, there's a missing `}` in stringified object which you have as value of property key.

Comment: Reason it is printing `0,1...` because your `dataOne.property` is string and it is printing all it's indexes.

Comment: @CodeManiac, sorry I left } while copying, I have copied properly now. Could you please tell me what's the solution to get keys

Comment: You need to parse value of property key, i.e `Object.keys(JSON.parse(dataOne.property))`

Comment: Use `Object.keys(JSON.parse(dataOne.property))` instead of `Object.keys(dataOne.property)`, because `dataOne.property` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON string to `object` as below:

```js
data = {"property" : "{\"animalID\": \"12345\", \"animalNumber\" : \"789\", \"type\" : \"mamal\"}"};

const dataOne = JSON.parse(data["property"]);
console.log("data", Object.keys(dataOne));
```